# Duplicate video when upload via youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I'm using Youtube API v3 to upload video. At the first time I use, it requires authorization then do upload but there are two videos is created. They are exactly the same but there is no error, the API returns the latest id. I checked in my channel, two videos could be view.
When I try to upload the previous video, another *id* returns, too, but if I use this, Youtube will show me "This video is a duplicate of another video". Other times, the API works right. Did anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: My telepathic skills aren't that good but yes I saw something getting repeated in your code.Regarding the second part, I have used v3 but never encountered such issue

Comment: I only use code from Youtube API page :|